# Add a custom view that includes more informations on google map markerTitle

Tags: ios, google-maps

[image]

The title and snippet property of GMSMarker all can not add a custom view. Who can tell me how to do that? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try delegate method `markerInfoWindow` like,

```
 -(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{


UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];

UILabel *label2;

UILabel *label3;

UIView *infoWindowView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];  //your desired frame

[infoWindowView addSubview:label1];
[infoWindowView addSubview:label2];
[infoWindowView addSubview:label3];

  return infoWindowView;
}
```

> Called when a marker is about to become selected, and provides an optional custom info window to use for that marker if this method returns a UIView. If you change this view after this method is called, those changes will not necessarily be reflected in the rendered version.
>   The returned UIView must not have bounds greater than 500 points on either dimension. As there is only one info window shown at any time, the returned view may be reused between other info windows.
>   Removing the marker from the map or changing the map's selected marker during this call results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see! I wang to give you a star! But where can i click?

Comment: You can accept an answer with right tick beside the answer if answer is correct!

Comment: Please waiting for minutes ... wuwu

Comment: I am so sorry! Ii is less than 15 reputations so that give a star, but my reputations is only 6.Sorry ....

Comment: I think you are new on SO, You should refer [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)